# What, if anything, is wrong with this proposal for faster-than-light communication using entanglement swapping?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

What, if anything, is wrong with this proposed mechanism for faster-than-light communication?

Here are pastes from the proposal:

> **Spooky Communication at a Distance**
>
> *Faster-Than-Light Communication via Quantum Entanglement Swapping Choice*
>
> **Introduction**
>
> Today it is widely accepted that quantum field theory cannot provide
> faster-than-light communication.  It is believed that although
> faster-than-light causal influences are possible (what Einstein called
> “spooky action at a distance”), nature conspires to prevent us from
> using these effects for communication. (Eberhard et al. 1989)
>
> In this piece I will counter this widely held notion by introducing a
> way to use quantum entanglement to communicate long distances
> faster-than-light. The proposed mechanism takes advantage of
> entanglement swapping and requires many sets of entangled pairs.
> Receiving messages before they are sent (spooky communication from the
> future) is also discussed.
>
> **Setup**
>
> A set of particles labeled 1, 2, 3, and 4 consist of two entangled
> pairs such that particles 1 and 2 are an entangled pair, and particles
> 3 and 4 are an entangled pair.
>
> Many sets of such particles are prepared and each set is labelled “a”
> through “n” such that
>
>  1a is entangled with 2a, 3a is entangled with 4a
>
>  1b is entangled with 2b, 3b is entangled with 4b
>
>  1c is entangled with 2c, 3c is entangled with 4c
>
>  …
>
>  1n is entangled with 2n, 3n is entangled with 4n
>
> The 1 and 4 particles from each set are transported a long distance to
> Alice, while the remaining 2 and 3 particles from each set remain with
> Victor.
>
> The quantity “n” of sets needs to be of sufficient size to account for
> the initial degree of entanglement between 1s and 2s and between 3s
> and 4s, as well as entanglement degradation, as well as to show
> statistically significant variation from Bell’s inequalities as
> explained later in the section on receiving data.
>
> **Sending Data via Choice Between Entanglement Swapping or No Swapping**
>
> At an appointed time, Victor will decide which bit of data to send to
> Alice (i.e. Victor will send either a 0 or 1). If Victor wishes to
> send a 1 he causes entanglement swapping such that the 1s and 4s are
> entangled.  For example, if using photons he could perform a
> Bell-state measurement (BSM) for the 2 and 3 particles from each set.
> BSM measurements cause entanglement swapping such that the 1 and 4
> particles in each set become entangled. If Victor wishes to send a 0
> he does not cause entanglement swapping.  For example, with photons he
> can perform a separable-state measurement (SSM) on the 2 and 3
> particles from each set. SSM measurements allow the 1 and 4 particles
> to remain separate and not entangled with each other.
>
> Victor performs the same measurement (BSM or SSM) for each set.  He
>
>  measures 2a and 3a
>
>  measures 2b and 3b
>
>  measures 2c and 3c
>
>  …
>
>  measures 2n and 3n
>
> It should be obvious that Victor could have multiple measurement
> machines operating in parallel to speed up the send process.
>
> This proposal relies on instantaneous entanglement swapping.  The 1
> and 4 pairs must become entangled with each other instantaneously upon
> BSM of the 2 and 3 particles.  (Or at least faster than the speed of
> light between Alice and Victor).
>
> **Receiving Data**
>
> To receive the message, at the appointed time Alice measures
> properties of particles 1 and 4 from each set.  Alice could have
> multiple reading machines in parallel to speed up the receive process.
>
> With a large enough number of sets (quantity “n”), Alice can determine
> whether the outcome of these measurements fit Bell’s inequalities.  If
> they are more statistically correlated than would be expected in a
> classical system, the 1 and 4 particles were entangled which means a
> “1” bit was received.  If the readings fit Bell’s inequalities the 1
> and 4 particles were not entangled and a “0” bit was received.
>
> Note that Alice does not need to know anything about particles 2 and 3, and
> does not need any classical communication from Victor.  With a large
> enough quantity “n” of sets and measurements, Alice can determine
> whether the 1s and 4s were entangled with each other or not (i.e. 1 or
> 0).

> **Implications, Discussion, and Conclusion**
>
> Combining the proposed communication mechanism with information from
> studies like “Experimental delayed-choice entanglement swapping” (Ma
> et al. 2012) it seems likely that a message can be received before it
> is sent.  In fact, a message can be received before the author of the
> message decides what to send.  This could be called “spooky
> communication from the future”.

> If my assumptions and understanding are correct, faster-than-light
> communication is possible.  If my assumptions and understanding are
> not correct, I hope to learn more.

> **References**
>
> Eberhard, Phillippe H.; Ross, Ronald R. (1989), "Quantum field theory
> cannot provide faster than light communication", Foundations of
> Physics Letters, 2 (2): 127–149, Bibcode:1989FoPhL...2..127E,
> doi:10.1007/BF00696109, S2CID 123217211
>
> Ma, Xs., Zotter, S., Kofler, J. et al. Experimental delayed-choice
> entanglement swapping. Nature Phys 8, 479–484 (2012).
> https://doi.org/10.1038/nphys2294

Comment: Can you summarize your question and make your point more clear?

Comment: @AmirhoseinRezaee I'm not sure how. One would need to know the proposal and some quantum theory to answer the question.  The proposal is pretty concise.  I guess you could just read the setup, send, and receive sections to save time.  The formatting is better in the google doc than the paste.

Comment: "...at the appointed time..." is doing some heavy lifting here.

Comment: @DmitryBrant  Imagine Alice and Victor are one light year apart.  They have pre-arranged that the appointed time is January 3, 2021 4:00:00 UTC.  Victor does his measurements starting at January 3, 2021 4:00:00 UTC and is done within 1 second.  Alice does her measurements and analyzes the results the next day on January 4, 2021.  Since she completed and analyzed the results before January 3, 2022 4:00:00 UTC (one year after Victor sent the message) she learned the message faster than classical communication.

Comment: *Today it is widely accepted that quantum field theory cannot provide faster-than-light communication*  It is not just "widely accepted"; it is **proved**.  In the time it took you to write all this up, you could have stepped through the proof of the no-communication theorem, applying each step to your particular protocol, and discovered your error for yourself.

Comment: Also, this us an instance of WillO's law:  Any proposed protocol that claims to exploit entanglement but does not specify either the entangled states or the exact measurements to be made is not worth reading.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [peer-review is off-topic here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7516/50583).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document cites "Experimental delayed-choice entanglement swapping" by Ma et al, which says:

> In the entanglement swapping procedure, two pairs of entangled photons are produced, and one photon from each pair is sent to Victor. [...] If Victor projects his two photons onto an entangled state, [the other] photons are entangled although they have never interacted or shared any common past.

So in essence you start with a state like $$(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)\otimes(|00\rangle+|11\rangle) = |0000\rangle+|0011\rangle+|1100\rangle+|1111\rangle$$

with Alice holding the first and fourth qubits and Victor the second and third. Victor then either does nothing, or else measures his qubits in a Bell basis—for instance, by performing a CNOT on qubit 3 with qubit 2 as the control, then measuring qubit 3. Supposing he does that, the new state is either $$|0000\rangle+|1101\rangle \qquad\text{or}\qquad |0011\rangle+|1110\rangle$$

depending on the measurement outcome (which isn't known to Alice).

If the state is the one on the left, and Alice measures her qubits at angles differing by $θ$, she'll get equal results with probability $\frac12(1+\cos\frac12θ)$. If the state is the one on the right then she'll get equal results with probability $\frac12(1-\cos\frac12θ)$. Each of these distributions individually violates Bell's inequality, but because there's a 50% chance of each one pertaining, she'll get equal results with probability $\frac12\left(\frac12(1+\cos\frac12θ)+\frac12(1-\cos\frac12θ)\right)=\frac12$ independent of $θ$, just as if her qubits were unentangled.

She can see a Bell's inequality violation if she postselects on a particular measurement outcome of Victor's, but she can't do that until she learns what Victor measured via some light-speed-limited channel.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read and respond.  Forget about Victor and consider this.  If Alice has many pairs of entangled photons would she be able to measure and see anything different with them than with a group of photons having no entanglement?

Comment: @user3141592 Many pairs in a known state, yes. The problem is half of them are correlated in one way and half in the opposite way and there's no way to know which is which.

Comment: Ok, after this comment and reading elsewhere I understand why Alice can not tell whether her pairs are entangled or not.  Thanks again!

Comment: Alice can't know if the 1s and 4s are entangled by measurements of 1s and 4s alone. That was the incorrect assumption with the proposal.  This is because the BSM to swap the entanglement causes some to be correlated and some anti-correlated and Alice won't know which are which.  It turns out that measurements can only be used to determine entanglement if the type of correlation for each pair is known.